# Asymmetric Ping Between Two Windows 7 Hosts

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-networking, network-protocols

Windows 7 Host A has two physical adapters, each with one IP:
10.20.157.10/24
10.20.159.10/24

Windows 7 Host B has two physical adapters, each with one IP:
10.20.156.10/24
10.20.158.10/24

Windows 7 Host A has two static routes:
10.20.156.0/24 via 10.20.157.1
10.20.158.0/24 via 10.20.157.1

Windows 7 Host B has two static routes:
10.20.157.0/24 via 10.20.156.1
10.20.159.0/24 via 10.20.156.1

On host A, I ping 10.20.158.10. The echo request egresses on the adapter with IP 10.20.157.10 and goes to gateway 10.20.157.1 for routing. A packet capture shows that the echo request successfully arrives at host B's 10.20.158.10 interface.

An echo reply should be generated with a destination IP address of 10.20.157.10 (from whence the echo request came). This would egress on the interface with IP address 10.20.156.10 and go to gateway 10.20.156.1 for routing. A packet capture shows that no such echo reply is generated.

The distinguishing characteristic of this situation is that the ingress and egress interfaces on host B are different.

I've been unable to find anything that says the echo reply should not be generated in this case.

Is this behavior of not allowing an echo reply to egress on an interface other than the one the echo request came in on correct or incorrect per RFCs, or do the RFCs leave the decision up to the implementation?

If the decision is left up to the implementation, is there a way to coerce Windows 7 into allowing the echo reply to go out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weak host" model needs to be used on the interfaces in question.

First, get the index of your red interfaces:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interface
```

Next, issue these commands (using interface indexes 13 and 15 as an example):

```
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 13 weakhostsend=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 15 weakhostsend=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 13 weakhostreceive=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 15 weakhostreceive=enabled
```

To check this setting, issue this command (using interface index 13 as an example):

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interface 13
```